# Dropdown is not showed completelly the first time the page showed

Tags: css

I have a dropdownlist declared like this:

```
<select id="PageToCreate_AuthorID">
<option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="1">Thierry</option>
<option value="2">Vanessa</option>
</select>
```

When the page is showed the fist time, here is what is displayed:

[image]

As you can see, we don't see all the text inside the control.

Then I click inside it and the dropdown is adjusted:

[image]

**How can I do to have the dropdown showed correctly when the page is showed the first time?**

Thanks.

Comment: What does the css look like, do you have an example on jsfiddle? Also, what browser(s)?

Comment: The problem occurs in IE8 only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some css for your select tag :

```
<select id="PageToCreate_AuthorID">
   <option value="">Please select...</option>
   <option value="1">Thierry</option>
   <option value="2">Vanessa</option>
</select>
```

Css:

```
#PageToCreate_AuthorID {
   min-width:200px; /* Change this value if you think you must do it */
}
```